# How to get the request metrics with WebClient or HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm trying to get the metrics (dns resolver time, tls handshake time...) associated to a single request and correlate the metrics with the response.

The purpose is to do a http request, process the response and store somewhere the status and the metrics of the requests.

`HttpClientMetricsHandler` and `HttpClientMetricsRecorder` are recording the metrics globally. It does not seems applicable.

I have started to look at redoing (but per request) what `HttpClientMetricsHandler` is doing and registering the custom handler by calling:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().doOnChannelInit(...)
```

The metrics of the request might be stored as an attribute of the channel and retrived by doing:

```
httpClient.get().responseConnection((httpClientResponse, connection) -> {
   connection.channel().attr()
});
```

It seems complex and I don't know if it is the best way to achieve my goals. Is there something simpler?

**EDIT**

I ended up using the [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) API

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
        .create()
        .doOnChannelInit((connectionObserver, channel, remoteAddress) -> {
            // Get the metrics bean from the context and propagate to the metrics handler  
            Metrics metrics = connectionObserver.currentContext().get("metrics");
            channel.pipeline().addAfter(NettyPipeline.ReactiveBridge,
                    NettyPipeline.HttpMetricsHandler, new HttpClientMetricsHandler(metrics));
        });


httpClient.get()
        .response()
        .map(httpClientResponse -> {
            // Get the metrics bean tied with the response 
            Metrics metrics = httpClientResponse.currentContextView().get("metrics");
            return true;

        })
        .contextWrite(ctx -> {
            // Add the metrics bean to the context
            return ctx.put("metrics", new Metrics());
        })
        .subscribe();
```

I'm still not sure it is not right way / best way to do it

Comment: Why not delegate such metrics collection to your infrastructure services such as ELK APM https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/index.html.

Comment: Elastic APM is only capturing the complete request timing and not its components. I don't really want to use an external tool to extract the information.